# Spring Boot HTTPS on localhost

Tags: spring, gradle, https

I had this working on localhost about a month ago, but when I came back to the project, hitting the URL results in a "This site can’t provide a secure connection" error in the browser. For reference, I believe I had used this site as a guide to get it set up: https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

I'm running the project with the `bootRun` Gradle task and the default embedded Tomcat server. The following configuration is set:

/grails-app/conf/application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: development
server:
  port: 8092
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias: alias
    key-password: password
```

The keystore is located at `/src/main/resources/keystore.jks`.

I don't see any errors in the console indicating any issues opening or accessing the keystore so I'm at a loss as to what might have changed. Is there a better guide than the one linked above that would give me other things to check for issues?

Comment: It's probably that the certificate expired, could you check it?

Comment: It's valid until 2030.

Comment: "I had this working about a month ago" was it also running on localhost or on remote host?

Comment: This was working on localhost for development and stopped working on localhost. Editing my original question with this detail.

Comment: So you use a self-signed certificate, right? probably you need intall it to your computer first, or it should say "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

Comment: I recreated a new keystore and cert. Then, I imported the cert into Windows Certificates (Local Computer) under Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

This didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Trying to connect to the server using openssl results in the following error which suggests that the application is trying to use ssl3.

140936:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version 
number:../openssl-1.1.1g/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:
331:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I tried changing the password field to something I knew was not the password and the app started without errors. This led me to determine that the YAML file was not being picked up by bootRun. Removing the Spring profile config at the top of the YAML file then caused the app to error because of the incorrect password.

This led me to realize that somehow the active profile configuration in my Gradle bootRun task was reset. Adding `-Dspring.profiles.active=development` to the VM options fixes the problem.